# Bootstrap input fields are not the same width when putting them in separate columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a form for online admissions using the Bootstrap framework. I am having a problem with putting two input fields in separate columns; those two fields are not adjusted according to the other fields' width. Here is my form code and also image of this problem:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="">
                        <h3>Personal Information</h3>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <span>Name</span>
                            <span><input type="username" class="form-control" id="userName"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div  class="form-group">
                            <span>Father Name</span>
                            <span><input type="username" class="form-control" id="userName"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <span>Nationality</span>
                                <span><input type="username" class="form-control" id="userName"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <span>Region</span>
                                <span><input type="username" class="form-control" id="userName"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <span>Date of Birth</span>
                                <span><input type="username" class="form-control" id="userName"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <span>Place of Birth</span>
                                <span><input type="username" class="form-control" id="userName"></span>
                            </div>
                            <h3></h3>
                        </div>
                        <div  class="form-group">
                            <span>Permanent Home Address</span>
                            <span><input type="username" class="form-control" id="userName"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div  class="form-group">
                            <span>e-mail</span>
                            <span><input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label class="fa-btn btn-1 btn-1e"><input type="submit" value="submit us"></label>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

[image]

Comment: Wrap your form groups in `<div class="row"></div>` or remove the padding from the col-xs-6 class

Comment: thanks @JB06 div with class row works

Comment: I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap's predefined grid classes to align labels and groups of form controls in a horizontal layout by adding .form-horizontal to the form (which doesn't have to be a ). Doing so changes .form-groups to behave as grid rows, so no need for .row.
**HTML**

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

To be using the boostrap form grid system correctly, you just need to warp the content of your first two inputs in a `.col-xs-12` class.

Like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <span>Name</span>
        <span><input type="username" class="form-control" id="userName">     

        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`col-xs-6` is adding the padding. You can wrap your groups in `col-xs-12`, or add a `col-xs-12` to each form group which should be full width.

Here is my plunker
[Working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/JRFD1frdh4PBwBagZcjC?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the form-groups in a `<div class="row"></div>`. This will remove the padding added by the col-xs-6 classes.